# Is it possible that the Linux page fault code in Kernel Oops is wrong?

Tags: linux, debugging, x86, kernel, x86-64

I stumbled upon a following bug during my linux boot:

```
[   16.489730] modprobe: Corrupted page table at address 7fef44115000
[   16.489820] PGD 104fbea067 PUD 84b1f9067 PMD 84b1df067 PTE 8000001050a3a025
[   16.490120] Bad pagetable: 0009 [#1] SMP
```

As far as I understand, the 0009 code indicates that reserve bit in of the table entries is written. However, I can't see anything like that in the page table entries that he gave to me. I could've blamed it on the 63'rd bit of the PTE entry, but I'm pretty sure that my IA32_EFER.NXE bit is turned on, so there should be no problem with it. So why does it gives that error code?